# Can a single Qt application open windows on more then one X display?

Tags: linux, qt, x11

I have a Qt application (running on Linux) that is supposed to open an extra window on a different X server,  running on a remote computer.

Is there a way to do this within Qt?

I hope to avoid more complex setups,  such as 
- DMX (virtual X-server on top of multiple other X servers) http://dmx.sourceforge.net/, or 
- creating a second application for the extra window, plus some kind of communication between the two applications

Comment: There can be only one `QApplication` object in the program, and one `QApplication` talks to one `Display` only. It's a fundamental limitation. So no, you can't do that within Qt.

Comment: Thanks,  n.-m. this is what I wanted to know.  I didn't see your answer at first,   because you added it as a comment instead of as an answer. I guess I cannot avoid creating a second application.

Answer (score 1):

You could try spawning a new process, and setting its DISPLAY environment variable to the other X server.

Try doing it from bash at first to see if it works, because I'm not entirely sure:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
./my_qt_application
```

Replace the `:0.0` with your other X server.

Comment: Works,  but does not really solve the problem: I will still have separate processes for the two displays,  and need to implement the communication between them.

Comment: Yes I saw your other answer, but needed some time to read the documentation for QX11EmbedWidget.

Comment: You're right, I deleted it. Well, then using another process would be your best bet. You can try using Xlib directly somehow, but I doubt it would work, and it wouldn't be very easy. I don't think there is an easy solution here.